# Regex - get n number of groups depending on number of delimiter separating them

Tags: java, regex

I have 2 linux commands called like this

```
ntpq -pn | sed -n '1,2!p' echo "%%%" chage -l root
```

The %%% is the delimiter I am using, for parsing the output.

The command above returns:

> remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset
> jitter
> ============================================================================
> *NTP_SERVER      SOME_IP_HERE     4 u   36 1024   77    0.511   -4.415    197.945 
> %%% 
> Password inactive                           : never
> Password expire                             : never\

The regex that I have `%%%((?:.*))` works fine when I want to take only the output of the second command, but what if I have more outputs behind this one separated with %%%. I want to take them in different groups too.

How can I transform my regex pattern so that it catches all the outputs in separate groups separated by the delimiter?

Comment: You may probably use `res.replaceFirst("(?s)^.*?%%%", "").split("%%%")`.

Comment: This is tagged Java. Where is the Java? If you mean to read lines of text into groups separated by a line of %%% then _regex is not the tool to use_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a multiline string with some unimportant text before the first `%%%` delimiter, you can remove this unimportant text first and then split with `%%%`:

```java
String[] entries = text.replaceFirst("(?s)^.*?%%%[\r\n]*", "").split("\\s*%%%\\s*");
```

See the [first regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OYXy5h/3) and the [second regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OYXy5h/4).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - `.` now matches any chars (same as [`Pattern.DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL))
- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `%%%` - a `%%%` string
- `[\r\n]*` - zero or more CR or LF chars.